# what is code compile unit in c# and how we can implement by CodeDom or any other alternative

Tags: c#, compilation

can any one explain what is **code compile unit** in *c#* with proper example.

how can we use CodeDom for code compile unit in c#.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeDOM is located in the System.CodeDom namespace.
The CodeCompileUnit that contains other elements such as namespaces, classes, methods, and individual statements.

Please look the below example:

```
 CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
    CodeNamespace myNamespace= new CodeNamespace(“MyNamespace”);
    myNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(“System”));
    CodeTypeDeclaration myClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration(“MyClass”);
    CodeEntryPointMethod start = new CodeEntryPointMethod();
    CodeMethodInvokeExpression cs1 = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(“Console”),
    “WriteLine”, new CodePrimitiveExpression(“Hello World!”));
    compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(myNamespace);
    myNamespace.Types.Add(myClass);
    myClass.Members.Add(start);
    start.Statements.Add(cs1);
```

Comment: hi mahen 
can you give a proper example.
how can i use above code in console application.